# Unable to view hidden directories although I am able to see hidden folders/files

Tags: dir

I store a backup of my music in an external HDD, G:. The main location is in E:. 
Although both folders have exactly the same folder structure and songs/album artworks, the main location has 6 more files. I managed to spot a folder which has 9 files on G: (8 songs + artwork) and 11 on E:. Therefore I ran a 'dir' on that folder getting the following output:

```
18/09/2016  23:03    <DIR>          .
18/09/2016  23:03    <DIR>          ..
15/09/2016  12:17        29.198.000 01 Μετρώντας Μέρες Αδράνειας.flac
15/09/2016  12:17        15.563.772 02 Δίχως Έλεος.flac
15/09/2016  12:17        20.850.419 03 Έρχεται Κηδεία.flac
15/09/2016  12:17        15.395.662 04 Αγανάκτηση και Υποταγή.flac
15/09/2016  12:17        23.176.140 05 Κάθε Μέρα Νεκροί.flac
15/09/2016  12:17        26.442.434 06 Δόγμα.flac
15/09/2016  12:17        18.061.713 07 Στο Βωμό της Εκδούλευσης.flac
15/09/2016  12:17        16.930.112 08 Απώλεια.flac
15/09/2016  12:04           161.964 Antimob.jpg
               9 File(s)    165.780.216 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  676.747.628.544 bytes free
```

It seems like that those 2 extra files are the directories that I am unable to view in order to delete. What are those? How were they created, and how can I delete them?

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about folders `.` and `..`, then do not try to delete them. Those are special folders meaning "current folder" and "parent folder" and should not be counted as members of a folder itself.

You can try those commands to understand it better:

- `cd .`: you will stay in the same folder, and
- `cd ..`: you will be moved to the parent folder.

Those two special folders exists in every folders on your system, hence they exists in both the source (`E:`) and backup copy (`G:`) of your music folder.

Maybe the source music folder contains some hidden items. If so you can show them with the command [`dir /ah`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx) (hidden items are not listed by default). If you are using Windows 10, then showing them on the graphical file Explorer is also easy (there is a direct button in the menu).